# jQuery select list inside table

Tags: jquery

I have this JSON data

```
data = [
  {"1":"Term 1","2":"Term 2","3":"Term 3"},
  {"1":"CAT 1","2":"CAT 2","3":"EoY"}
]
```

and need to create a table with the first element as headers and the second element a select list inside the table.

my table has two rows: so far this is what i have:

for table structure:

```
<div id='tableSearchDiv'>
    <table id='tableSearch'>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

function to create the table:

```
function modalTableFirst(data) {
  //create a select box with  categories
  var sel = $("<select id=\'selectId\' name=\'selectName\' />");
  //create the options using the passed json element
  $.each(data[1],function(k,v){
    $("<option />",{value:k,text:v}).appendTo(sel);
  });

  //create the table headers for the results search
  var tContents = "";
  tContents += "<tr>";
  $.each(data[0],function(key,value){
    tContents += "<th>" + value + "</th>";
  });
  tContents += "</tr><tr>";

  $("#tableSearch").html(tContents);
}
```

I need each column of the header to have the same select list in the second row as below

**term1                     term2                  term3**

[select]           [select]           [select]

my question is how do I append the select list in the second row under each column?any pointer much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do what I wanted extracting the outerHTML of the select object and concatenating to tContents

```
var extTags = sel.get(0).outerHTML;
tContents += "<tr><td>" + extTags + "</td></tr>"
```